# #include-ing certain header files in old C source (page.h et al) on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I'm new to GNU/Linux (Lubuntu 11.10) and am trying to compile some C source code out of a Linux programming book from 2001. Am somewhat confused about the inclusion of header files in GNU/Linux.

The program is "simplefb.c" from the book **Programming Linux Games** by John R. Hall et al (2001). I jumped straight to the chapter on console programming with framebuffer but hit this immediate snag. Would just like to make some simple non-GUI (and non-'text') games in C on Linux for fun...

The problem seems to be with a few #includes to header files:

```
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
```

Trying the code as given in the book:

**> cc the_file.c**
gives
*fatal error: asm/page.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.*

And indeed it seems that these files live somewhere else (nowadays?) so I tried amending initially just the first #include to:

```
#include </usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include/asm-generic/page.h>
```

I chose this particular folder of headers (there are several in /usr/src/) because
**> uname -r**
*3.0.0-17-generic*

With the amended #include, I then get the compilation error:

In file included from the_file.c
*/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include/asm-generic/page.h:96:38: fatal error: asm-*
generic/memory_model.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

And looking in that page.h, it specifies
include asm-generic/memory_model.h
(removed the hashs and 'tags' as this line won't show up here properly otherwise)
but this file does exist in the same folder.

So, before I go on a wild-goose-chase (firstly removing the asm-generic/ bit of the previous include and putting it in quotes), what is the correct procedure I should be using here? Is there an obvious right way to get the book source code to compile?

Thank you. Will be most grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two different sets* of header files: one for Linux kernel programming, the other for general user-space programs.

/usr/src/linux* is for the kernel stuff.

/usr/include/* are the "normal" headers.

You do *not* want to mix'n'match the two.

If you're programming a game, I'd strongly encourage you to look at SDL or OpenGL:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6410
- http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/63945-game-programming-in-linux-for-windows-programmers-part-1/

ADDENDUM:

1. The problem is you're missing the fbdev (user-space) headers.  You do NOT want to bring in any Linux kernel source headers.
2. You should be able to get the header with this command:

   `sudo apt-get xserver-xorg-video-fbdev`
3. You might need to bring in other dependencies as well - apt-get should tell you.

'Hope that helps .. PSM

PS:

It appears that your book, "Programming Linux Games" is also a well-regarded tutorial on SDL.

Comment: Addendum: I downloaded the sample code from your book here:  http://nostarch.com/download/plg-listings-08-07-2001.tar.gz  You absolutely want the user-space headers (e.g. /usr/include/linux/fb.h) and NOT the Linux kernel headers!

Answer (score 0):

The `-I` argument to gcc adds a directory to look for header files in.

```
gcc ... -I /usr/src/.../include ...
```